# I am getting a Path/File access error in my VBA code? Why is that so?

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a

> Run-time error '75':
>   Path/File access error

in my VBA code and I am not sure about the reason behind that error.

When I debugged the code I saw this particular line as the error line:

```
Name strPath & cell.Value As strPath & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Full code is:

```
Sub RenameFiles()

    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "C:\Users\Satish Muppidi\Downloads\"

    Dim srcrng As Range
    Set srcrng = Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

        For Each cell In srcrng

            Name strPath & cell.Value As strPath & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Next cell

    Range("A1").Select

    End Sub
```

Please help me in updating the code.

Comment: Would be better if you use just code instead of images. Image can be deleted and question-answer can become useless for community.

Comment: Do cells `A2` and `B2`contain filenames?  And nothing except for filenames in columns A & B below row 2?

Comment: Yes A2 and B2 have filenames. No, there are multiple filenames below A2 and B2

Comment: Do you have update access to the directory?  (Try renaming one of the files manually using Windows Explorer and see if it lets you.)

Comment: Rather than use `Set srcrng = Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown))` which will return all rows if there's only a value in A2, use `Set srcrng = Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))` instead.  I think your main problem is as @HarassedDad says in his answer though (which could be linked to `Set srcrng` problem finding empty cells).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't check for the existence of the file before you try to rename it. Try

```
 If Dir(strpath & cell.value) = "" then

 else
     Name strPath & cell.Value As strPath & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 
End if
```